# Wicket in Liferay

Tags: liferay

Just want to know any one integrated wicket with liferay.
How difficult it is to code the wicket portlet with ajax enabled ?

Any one using wicket portlets in production ?

Answer (score 4):

Right now we're developing Liferay-based portal that uses portlets that were written in Wicket. We're using Wicket 1.4 because it was the last version with out of the box support for the portlets.

There's guide about developing portlets for Liferay in Wicket: [How to build a Wicket AJAX Portlet in Liferay’s Eclipse IDE](http://i-proving.com/2010/09/07/how-to-build-a-wicket-ajax-portlet-in-liferays-eclipse-ide).

In addition, I wrote several posts in Russian recently about developing simple AJAX-enabled Wicket portlet for Liferay 6.0.6 and attempted to describe all the possible "pitfalls" there. I'm not so comfortable with English right now to translate them but you could take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/shafranov/wicket-liferay-portlet). Comments are in English.

Answer (score 0):

I developed some portlet based apps in wicket + spring + hibernate, deployed in liferay, and was happy with it, until wicket drop the support for portlet.
The last supported version was 1.4.x.

So i suggest you :

- if you want to build the non portlet apps, i RECOMMEND you to use wicket (newest is version 7)
- if you want to build portlet based apps, consider using [Primefaces - JSF Based Framewok](http://primefaces.org/). This is my second favorite framework after Wicket. I am using this framework for production.

Answer (score 0):

Apache wicket 7.3.0-SNAPSHOT supports portlets in liferay 6.1 and liferay 6.2.
You can download the wicket portlet examples project from here:
https://github.com/kkaravitis/core/tree/master/portlet-parent/wicketstuff-portlet-examples